# How to preserve YAML comments (#) by yaml.load() in R

Tags: r, yaml

I need to load a yaml file, update some values and write back to file. The ymal file contains many comments (after a # sign) which I want to preserve. Tried to use the r ymal package, but the load function strips the comments.

```
yaml.load("- hey\n- hi\n- hello #comments")
```

Are there parameters to preserve the comments? another package to solve the issue?
Thanks!

update:after reading [here](https://github.com/yaml/libyaml/issues/42) and [here](https://github.com/snoyberg/yaml/issues/111) I understood that there is no solution yet in yaml package. I have a workaround when reading and writing to a file:

```
#load original yaml file as text table separated by #
# !!! Note: make sure there are no # inside the comments !!!
origin_yaml <- read.delim("gotm.yaml",sep="#", header = FALSE)

# load original yaml file with yaml parser, 
data <- read_yaml("gotm.yaml")
# make some update (not in this example code)

#write to updated file again
write_yaml(data,"gotm.yaml")

#load the modified yaml file as text table, striped from the comments because yaml parser do that.
modif_yaml <- read.delim("gotm.yaml",sep="#", header = FALSE)
    
# Add the comments column to the modified yaml file
modif_yaml$V2 <- origin_yaml$V2

# write the file back
write.table(modif_yaml,file="gotm.yaml", sep = "#", row.names = FALSE, col.names = FALSE, quote = FALSE)
```